# WooCommerce All in One Currency Converter plugin doesn't convert currency for price updated by WooCommerce Custom Fields plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, currency, custom-fields, price

I am using two plugins one is **WooCommerce Custom Fields** for some extra option fields on my product page which is working fine and changing the price on option selection , but it does not work with **WooCommerce All in One Currency Converter** plugin.

**For example:**
Price for product is set as **`10 usd`**.
Then there is a custom field selector to select an option which will increase the price by **`5 usd`**.

Now if the currency plugin changed my currency to **`Indian rupee`**, **custom field price** is not getting converted to **`indian rupee`**, and it will just increase the price by **`5 rupee`**.

Any compatible plugin for this? 
Or some solution to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: are you talking about **Advanced Custom Fields** plugin, as there isn't any **WooCommerce Custom Fields** plugin. Please update your question.

Comment: Also, have you tried contacting the authors of the plugins in question?

Comment: @ LoicTheAztec
No i am using this 
https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-custom-fields-product-addons/11332742

Comment: @ helgatheviking
yes i have contacted with both plug's author , and they said there is no compatibility between two .Thats why i am searching for solution by either way.